# A: How to set new position on label in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i'm use this code..but it gives error ,how can i fix it

lb1[a].Location = new Point(b, 50);

in here i want to set the label position using ASP.net. Is that "location" key word not supported to the ASP.net???

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set the position of a label, you probably want to use CSS.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" CssClass="labellocation" />

.labellocation { position: absolute; top: 500px; }
```

Comment: i'm use this code section for that. so how can i manage with it??
 for (int a = 0; a < numbers.Length; a++)
  {
     lb[a] = new Label();
     lb[a].Height = 50;
     lb[a].Width = 50;
     lb[a].Text = numbers[a].ToString();
     lb[a].BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
     lb[a].BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Double;
     lb[a].Style = new Point(b, 75);
     b = b + 75;
     this.Panel2.Controls.Add(lb[a]);
     Panel2.Refresh()
}

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: So you're adding Labels dynamically to a Panel? You're trying to position the Labels within the panel?

Answer (score 0):

Set the position using css (looks as if you are using absolute positioning):

```
.classname {    
    position: absolute;  
    top: 20px;  
    left: 50px;
}
```

If you want to add the class dynamically:

```
lb1.Attributes.Add("classname", "3");
```